# Using ColorStateList in Android Java code

Tags: android, background-color

I have a list with items, and 2 colorliststates, one for the odds, one for the evens.
basically, it ressembles this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#fff" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#999" />
</selector>
```

How can I use apply the colorliststate to the items? in the layout, there is no notion of odd or even, so i can't. In the java code, I can't find a way of using the colorliststate once i load it :

```
getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.list_even);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the solution seems to define the colors in a values xml file, and then use these in xml drawables selectors

Comment: my understanding is the answer basically is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// you must place your file in the res/color folder
widget.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.list_even));
```

Or just put it in the `textColor` attribute if you are using XML:

```
<SomWidget
    android:textColor="@color/list_even"/>
```

Comment: that does not seems to work with background, actually. it keeps saying there is no drawable attribute

Answer (score 0):

**First** define two different selector drawables. You can refer in the drawable xml to a color.xml or enter directly the color value. To use the color.xml is more fancy.

**Second**
I guess you have ListAdapter implementation. So in your getView(..) implementation you can set different background drawables for odd and even items. I guess you want to modify the background and not the text color because you posted an example referring to a pressed state.

Expressed in code, without having eclipse here and totally correct Syntax in mind:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
  view.setBackGroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector1);
}
else {
  view.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector2);
}
```

Does my example match what you want?

Comment: not entirely. I figure the setBackgroundDrawable part, but i don't see what to do with a colorListState.

Comment: you mean i should first define the colors, and then use them as drawables in a selector ?

Comment: I mean that you don't need a selector. I think you want to adjust the color by the even/odd state, which can not be reflected by a selector. You need to set the desired color in the list adapter. Maybe you can adjust your question to clarify what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: as stated in the question, there is also the matter of pressed/not pressed that changes the color (which, far as i know is solved using a  state list selector)

Comment: Ok, think i got what you mean. I edited the question. Does it help?