# Android: Selector isn't working as expected in TableRow selection

Tags: android, colors, selector, tablerow

I have a TAbleLayout in my XML with 1 row i.e. te headings row. Other all rows, I add dynamically. I want to make a row selected on clicking it & on touching it. I added clickListener to each row and am able to trap click event. But when the mouse is pressed or kept pressed, I see color change, then again it comes to normal color. I want the color to stay changed until I click other row or click somewhere else to deactivate the selected row.

My selector XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<!--  Active state -->  
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />      
<!--  Inactive state-->  
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
 <!--  Pressed state --> 
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />

<!--  Selected state (using d-pad) -->  
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
       android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
```

My Java code where I generate rows dynamically :

```
private void createView(TableRow tr, TextView tv, String data, int rowId) {
    tv.setText(data);

    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);

    tr.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1);
    //tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    tr.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tablerowselector));
    tr.setId(rowId);
    tr.setClickable(true);
    tr.setFocusable(true); // Added thinking that if its not focusable then it can't be selected, but makes no difference
    tr.setOnClickListener(this);
    tr.addView(tv);
}
```

If I handle in clickListener event, and set Background color of row based on setting `prevRowSelected` and `currRowSelected` logic, that works. But how to make selector work and why it is not working ? Can't selector work the way am trying to achieve it ?

Thanks

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't put here something. Where have you got tablerowselector? Where are you changing the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends, selector, doesn't work as I had expected. So have handled it programmatically using apprpriate logic and setting row's color.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Hi, Can you please specify as to what changes you made to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have to change the selector. I have found the recipes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)

Comment: I have already looked over the sites that you provide here. None of them match my requirements. If I have to make different StateListDrawables dynamically only, then using just setBackground(color) sounds more simple and easy.