# ImageButton background swiching on it's own? Drawables gone wild?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I having an issue where the ImageButton background is being drawn with a different drawable from one of my resources.  I'm setting the background to be transparent but on some cases it's picking up one of my drawables called bottom_shadow.9.png. Why why!? It's freaking weird...

I've seen this issue before... Some of my app users have complained seeing this issue and now I'm determined to figure this out! Take a look below what I currently have. Any tips or ideas would help.

The color value I created under values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

My ImageButton under my one xml layout under layout/:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibHelp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/settings_list_item_height"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_more_information"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_help" />
```

This is what I'm seeing on the generated R.java file:

```
public static final class drawable {
  public static final int bottom_shadow=0x7f020000;
}

public static final class color {
  public static final int transparent=0x7f080009;
}
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes something in Eclipse goes wrong and I see wrong resources in the wrong places in the app. In these cases cleaning of the project helps for me (Project -> Clean).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did notice that doing a clean helps.  This issue kinda sucks...  Sometimes there is no way to reproduce it and than on a certain phone the issue happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be related to this issue?

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20283

Comment: Right on the money! :) Thanks a lot for the link! It's exactly that!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are facing the same issue as I on another project : When using the transparent color #00000000 on a background, Android will not actually make it transparent but instead use the background drawable of the element directly under it.

Not sure what I've just said is clear but to check if this is it, I found a quick and easy solutions : Don't use #00000000 as your background transparent but any other completely transparent color : #00FF0000 or even #00F00000 should do it.

See the issue I raised in Google tracker : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24653

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do understand what you are saying about transparent value all zeros.  I'm wondering if Android has issues also for picking not just the background directly under it but picking a random drawable.  In my case it's a random drawable not even used on this particular fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating your own color when it's built into Android.R.color? I would try using:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Whether or not it fixes your problem, it's simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback... However it doesn't matter what color I use, the issue will still happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna your button's background to be some kind of color, but you have assigned both a src and a color of the button(in the layout xml), which means that the button may use the src picture as the background, not a pure color. I don't know if I made the point.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you wrote... But declaring a src and background is a valid use of ImageButton.  I don't see anywhere on the Android APIs about not using a color resources together with a drawable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, I was seeing really strange periodic display corruption in my transparent ImageButton background because I was specifying the items in my background selector as follows:

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

This *might* seem to work occasionally, but I definitely had cases where the ImageButtons would render with a ghastly all-white background instead of the nice transparent background.

Note that I was mixing up the android:drawable syntax with a color resource. The correct way to specify a color resource seems to be either an android:color="#FF00FF" attribute or as a child element of item using a  element. I searched long and hard, and eventually found this post.