# selector for listview doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to set the color of row in listview if selected to yellow and otherwise be white so I use the following selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/encounter_normal"  />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/encounter_normal" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/encounterselector_color" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/encounter_normal"  />
</selector>
```

where

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="encounterselector_color">#fbeda5</color>
    <color name="encounter_normal">#ffffff</color>  
</resources>
```

and I use it like the following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    android:id="@+id/EncounterGrid"
    android:background="@drawable/encounterlistview"

    >
 <!-- remaining code -->
```

but the row is always white , any idea how to fix that

Comment: what is name of selector and where is your <ListView> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color with a selector is a bit tricky. Basically you have to create a drawable for each color and use them in your `android:drawable` attributes. You cannot directly use colors.

Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- This is the switched off state -->
<item   android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grey_bar" />

<!-- These are the partial states -->
<item   android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />        

<item   android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" />

<!--  This is the switched on state -->
<item   android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Where all of the drawables I point to are defined in xml, or are existing 9 patch images.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:color` on your selector and not `android:drawable` because you are getting reference to the color resources, so your selector will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/encounter_normal"  />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/encounter_normal" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/encounterselector_color" />
    <item
     android:color="@color/encounter_normal"  />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working for me until I set `drawSelectorOnTop = "true"`.

Everything worked after that.