# Change "on" color of a Switch

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm using a standard Switch control with the holo.light theme in a ICS app.

I want to change the highlighted or on state color of the Toggle Button from the standard light blue to green.

This should be easy, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

Comment: I don't really see any other way than copying the relevant platform resources (selector and *.png files) and modify the 'on' state drawable. Don't forget to point the `Switch` to this custom selector afterwards.

Comment: **2021** for anyone googling this very old question, it is now very easy, answer of @مهند عطية below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362379/294884

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As of now it is better to use SwitchCompat from the AppCompat.v7 library. You can then use simple styling to change the color of your components.

```
values/themes.xml:

<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

ref: [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

**EDIT**:

The way in which it should be correctly applied is through `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"` 
and also this can be applied to parent styles such as EditTexts, RadioButtons, Switches, CheckBoxes and ProgressBars:

```
<style name="My.Widget.ProgressBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">

<style name="My.Widget.Checkbox" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
```

Comment: Although not applicable at the time, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Have changed this to the accepted answer, as it seems the more "modern" approach to this question.

Comment: I tried all of these and none of them changed the color of the "on" state for my switch.

Comment: 'on' is `colorAccent`, 'off' is `colorSwitchThumbNormal`.  If using the `AppCompat` theme, you need to use `SwitchCompat` rather than `Switch`.  If using SDK 23+, you can use `android:thumbTint` and `android:thumbTintMode` with a `ColorStateList`.

Comment: @Tom plz reply will those 'android:thumbTint' things will work on devices < 23

Comment: Would anyone suspect this not to work when my app's base them includes a "colorAccent" field with a different value? I am trying to make an active switch (with "colorAccent") blue when the base theme "colorAccent" is pink. It looks like I am unable to "overwrite" the pink color from the base theme, which is not what I would expect.

Comment: Note that this didn't won't work for me when I had SwitchCompat instead of switch. Took me a while to figure it out. hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: the texton and textoff colors change as well, how do i set them to different color?

Comment: This fixed it: <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/white</item>

Answer (score 335):

Late to party but this is how I did

**Style**

```
 <style name="SCBSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#46bdbf</item>

        <!-- inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#f1f1f1
        </item>

        <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f
        </item>
    </style>
```

**Colors**

[image]

**Layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch" />
```

**Result**

See change of colors  for enables and disabled switch

[image]

Comment: @MaksimKniazev You have to use `SwitchCompat` ;)

Comment: Good, except of colorControlActivated - it doesn't set track color, only thumb color.

Comment: here is solution for Switch and SwitchCompat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036089/5869630

Comment: <style> tags needed to be written under res>>values>>styles.xml and on XML page for <Switch ...> you should add only the line called: android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch  and my colors are: colorControlActivated">#ff0000 and colorSwitchThumbNormal">#00ff00 and android:colorForeground">#00ff00

Comment: @OviTrif Awesome! It is impressive how hard it is to find a simple information like that. Lots and lots of answers I've been reading, and nobody, gave a working answer until now. Finally!

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm.

Comment: If inactive track's color is not being changed with above style's item, give it a try:         <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>

Answer (score 66):

As an addition to existing answers: you can customize thumb and track using selectors in `res/color` folder, for example:

**switch_track_selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/lightBlue"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey"/>
</selector>
```

**switch_thumb_selector**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/darkBlue"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Use these selectors to customize track and thumb tints:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:trackTint="@color/switch_track_selector"
    app:thumbTint="@color/switch_thumb_selector"/>
```

Keep in mind that if you use standart `Switch` and `android` namespace for these attributes, it will only work for API 23 and later, so use `SwitchCompat` with `app` namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as universal solution.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't have res/color folder

Answer (score 53):

This is working for me (requires Android 4.1):

```
Switch switchInput = new Switch(this);
int colorOn = 0xFF323E46;
int colorOff = 0xFF666666;
int colorDisabled = 0xFF333333;
StateListDrawable thumbStates = new StateListDrawable();
thumbStates.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
thumbStates.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
thumbStates.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(colorOff)); // this one has to come last
switchInput.setThumbDrawable(thumbStates);
```

Note that the "default" state needs to be added last as shown here.

The only problem I see is that the "thumb" of the switch now appears larger than the background or "track" of the switch. I think that's because I'm still using the default track image, which has some empty space around it. However, when I attempted to customize the track image using this technique, my switch appeared to have a height of 1 pixel with just a sliver of the on/off text appearing. There must be a solution for that, but I haven't found it yet...

**Update for Android 5**

In Android 5, the code above makes the switch disappear completely. We should be able to use the new [setButtonTintList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) method, but this seems to be ignored for switches. But this works:

```
ColorStateList buttonStates = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                new int[]{}
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.RED,
                Color.GREEN
        }
);
switchInput.getThumbDrawable().setTintList(buttonStates);
switchInput.getTrackDrawable().setTintList(buttonStates);
```

**Update for Android 6-7**

As Cheruby stated in the comments, we can use the new `setThumbTintList` and that worked as expected for me. We can also use `setTrackTintList`, but that applies the color as a blend, with a result that's darker than expected in dark color themes and lighter than expected in light color themes, sometimes to the point of being invisible. In Android 7, I was able to minimize that change that by overriding the track [tint mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html), but I couldn't get decent results from that in Android 6. You might need to define extra colors that compensate for the blending. (Do you ever get the feeling that Google doesn't want us to customize the appearance of our apps?)

```
ColorStateList thumbStates = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                new int[]{}
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.RED,
                Color.GREEN
        }
);
switchInput.setThumbTintList(thumbStates);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
    ColorStateList trackStates = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.GRAY,
                    Color.LTGRAY
            }
    );
    switchInput.setTrackTintList(trackStates);
    switchInput.setTrackTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the getThumbDrawable/getTrackDrawable approach to create a switch where both states have the same color - in other words, the switch doesn't enable/disable something, but is used for a choice between two alternatives.

Comment: Got that DrawableCompat.setTintList will allow it to work on previous devices. I call: DrawableCompat.setTintList(switchCompat.getThumbDrawable(), foregroundState);

Comment: Please edit the answer to include the DrawableCompat solution. It works perfectly!

Comment: API 23+: `switchInput.setThumbTintList(buttonStates);`  works for Nougat as well.

API 21-22:  
Use the DrawableCompat as suggested by @Alexey. The `switchInput.setButtonTintList(buttonStates);` didn't work for me, it didn't color the states for my Switch.  

API below 21:  `switchInput.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(someColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);`  

These worked for me. I worked with Xamarin as well, so translate those to C# in the Android renderers if you use Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 53):

make drawable "newthumb.xml"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/Green" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/Red" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

and make drawable "newtrack.xml"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

and add it in Switch:

```
<Switch
  android:trackTint="@drawable/newtrack"
  android:thumbTint="@drawable/newthumb"
/>
```

Use `app:trackTint` and `app:thumbTint` instead for switch compat androidx – see @Ehsan Rosdi's comments.

Also, it's perfectly OK to make only one drawable file ("switchcolors.xml") and use that for both trackTint and thumbTint.

Comment: This works. However, it should be noted that AndroidStudio will not be able to suggest @drawable resources for `trackTint` or `thumbTint`. One needs to write it in manually and it works.

Comment: For some reason this is the only answer that works reliably on my Huawei. Thanks!

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH

Comment: SENT A BOUNTY !

Comment: use app:trackTint and app:thumbTint instead for switch compat androidx

Comment: @EhsanRosdi you should add your comment as an answer. I spent a couple minutes scrolling and reading before I came upon your comment.

Comment: trackTint is a color, you can't set a drawable to it.

Answer (score 51):

To change Switch style without using style.xml or Java code, you can customize switch into layout XML :

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:thumbTint="@color/blue"
        android:trackTint="@color/white"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It's attribute **android:thumbTint** and **android:trackTint** that allowed you to customize color

This is the visual result for this XML :

[image]

Comment: This changes the color of the thumb, no matter if it's turned on or off.

Comment: "Attribute thumbTint is only used in API level 21 and higher"

Comment: @norbDEV use app:thumbTint and app:trackTint with the SwitchCompat from the AppCompat.v7 library for a lower API level.

Comment: That works, but what if you want to change the color for thumb, depending on whether it's on or off?

Comment: If you want to use *thumbTint* below 21 the use `app:thumbTint` instead of `android:thumbTint` and change `switch` with `SwitchCompat`

Comment: @TavernSenses for differentiating the color between on and off apply a color state list to the tint property, one color for state_checked="true" and another for false

Answer (score 37):

Create a custom Switch and override setChecked to change color:

```
  public class SwitchPlus extends Switch {

    public SwitchPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwitchPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwitchPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(checked);
        changeColor(checked);
    }

    private void changeColor(boolean isChecked) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            int thumbColor;
            int trackColor;

            if(isChecked) {
                thumbColor = Color.argb(255, 253, 153, 0);
                trackColor = thumbColor;
            } else {
                thumbColor = Color.argb(255, 236, 236, 236);
                trackColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            try {
                getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(thumbColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(trackColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first post that actually helped me achieved custom color for the Material  Switch without using style or themes. Thanks !

Comment: Nice. I already had my own customized Switch, so I've only had to override the setChecked method and all of them automatically changed their colors. Thanks from Spain.

Answer (score 35):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:thumbTint="@color/white"
                app:trackTint="@drawable/checker_track"/>
```

And inside checker_track.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/lightish_blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/hint" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: `thumbTint` only applies on Android API 21 and above. How if i want to change the colour on below Android 21?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat SwitchCompat is backward compatible with API 7 and above

Comment: It is 2020. I really wonder where in the world people still using Android 21 and below?

Answer (score 33):

While answer by SubChord is correct, is doesnt really answer the question of how to set the "on" color without also affecting other widgets. To do this, use a `ThemeOverlay` in styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToggleSwitchTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_bright</item>
</style>
```

And reference it in your switch:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
  android:theme="@style/ToggleSwitchTheme" ... />
```

In so doing it will ONLY affect the color of the views you want to apply it to.

Comment: For some reason, I also had to set "colorControlActivated" to the same value, yet on POC, it was enough to use "colorAccent". How come?

Answer (score 20):

I solved it by updating the Color Filter when the Switch was state was changed...

```
public void bind(DetailItem item) {
    switchColor(item.toggle);
    listSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                switchColor(b);
        }
    });
}

private void switchColor(boolean checked) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        listSwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(checked ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        listSwitch.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(!checked ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

May be its a bit late, but for switch buttons, toogle button is not the answer, you must change the drawable in the xml parameter of the switch:

```
 android:thumb="your drawable here"
```

Answer (score 10):

**This worked for me -:**

1.code in **values/styles.xml** -:

```
 <style name="SwitchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#148E13</item>
</style>
```

2.add following line of code in your **switch** in your **layout** file -:

```
android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
```

Comment: Best and simple solution

Answer (score 9):

In Android Lollipop and above, define it in your theme style:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Material.Theme">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/color_switch</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it also changes the colors of my selected textedits which is not what I want.

Comment: @codewing Of course it will. Because this is set in global style preference. In order to achieve your goal, is to find the view id of your target view and modify its attributes.

Comment: OK, that's for the "On" position. What about changing the thumb color for the "Off" position?

Answer (score 6):

Create your own 9-patch image and set it as the background of the toggle button.

http://radleymarx.com/2011/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: Yeah, could do that, but surely there MUST be an easier way? Selectors maybe?

Comment: No, there is no easier way. You can't magically change the color of an image :)

Comment: Good point. I didn't fully get how it worked until I had a deeper look.

Comment: @Denizen, Are you sure? If so, post an answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: @Denizen Please remove your comment.  Android Switch always returns null for getBackground(), I wasted 30 minutes trying this.

Answer (score 5):

The solution suggested from arlomedia worked for me.
About his issue of extraspace I solved removing all the paddings to the switch.

EDIT

As requested, here what I have.

In the layout file, my switch is inside a linear layout and after a TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg_myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextForTheSwitch"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/TextForTheSwitch"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_white" />
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOn="@string/On"
            android:textOff="@string/Off"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myTextForTheSwitch"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/myTextForTheSwitch"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Since I'm working with Xamarin / Monodroid (min. Android 4.1) my code is:

```
Android.Graphics.Color colorOn = Android.Graphics.Color.Green;
Android.Graphics.Color colorOff = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
Android.Graphics.Color colorDisabled = Android.Graphics.Color.Green;

StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
drawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked }, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
drawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled }, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
drawable.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(colorOff));

swtch_EnableEdit.ThumbDrawable = drawable;
```

swtch_EnableEdit is previously defined like this (Xamarin):

```
Switch swtch_EnableEdit = view.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.mySwitch);
```

I don't set at all the paddings and I don't call .setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0).

Comment: Can you provide code for that? I tried switchInput.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0) but nothing changed.

Comment: Tested in Xamarin using the AppCompat library to target 5.x and this worked as advertised.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is defining track tint, and setting tint mode to src_over to remove 30% transparency.

```
android:trackTint="@drawable/toggle_style"
android:trackTintMode="src_over"
```

toggle_style.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/informationDefault"
        android:state_checked="true"
        />
    <item android:color="@color/textDisabled" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can make custom style for switch widget 
 that use color accent as a default when do custom style for it

```
<style name="switchStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>    <!-- set your color -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this lib, easy to change color for the switch button.
https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out right answer here: [Selector on background color of TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview).
In two words you should create Shape in XML with color and then assign it to state "checked" in your selector.

Comment: Nice solution, but do you know how can we change the color dynamically?

Comment: You just need to set the selector as the background resource

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to do it from java , But if you have a style defined for your app you can add this line in your style and you will have the desired color  for me i have used  #3F51B5

```
<color name="ascentColor">#3F51B5</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml , you can change the color as :

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/notificationSwitch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    app:thumbTint="@color/darkBlue"
    app:trackTint="@color/colorGrey"/>
```

Dynamically you can change as :

```
Switch.thumbDrawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.darkBlue), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a combination of a few of the answers here, this is what has worked for me.

```
<Switch
    android:trackTintMode="src_over"
    android:thumbTint="@color/white"
    android:trackTint="@color/shadow"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the tint colour for track and thumb drawable.

```
switch.getThumbDrawable().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));

switch.getTrackDrawable().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 0):

Programattically if you want to change Switch Component Color use this code below:

```
    binding.switchCompatBackupMedia.thumbTintList =
                ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#00C4D3"))
            binding.switchCompatBackupMedia.trackTintList =
                ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#00C4D31F"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm android developer recently I have to maintain an old application, so I need to add Material Components 3 and update to `androidx.core` and `androidx.appcompat`. As you might understand my idea was to reuse the maximum code as I could. But I face some problems for example. Change the `switch` button color. I tried all the techniques I know and I follow all the answers in this thread.

So I found a solution by myself combining all the answers and suggestions here.

Lets start with the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    ...
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 3004006
        versionName "3.4.6"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    ...
}
```

We are using these dependencies and some configuration like `minSdk 21` and `targetSdk 33` so we can target almost 99% of the devices.

What I want is to change the color of the switch button defined in the `preferences.xml` file Originally I was using `SwitchPreference` but I couldn't change the color neither the thumb nor the track. I tried using custom colors modifying the `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent` or directly setting `app:thumbTint` and `app:trackTint`. Finally I decided to extend the `SwitchPreference` class. like this:

First create a new layout `preference_material_switch.xml` with for the MaterialSwitch

```xml
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

```kotlin
class CustomSwitchPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    SwitchPreference(context, attrs) {

    private var materialSwitch: MaterialSwitch? = null

    init {
        widgetLayoutResource = R.layout.preference_material_switch
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)

        materialSwitch =
            holder.findViewById(androidx.preference.R.id.switchWidget) as MaterialSwitch?
        materialSwitch?.isChecked = isChecked
    }

    override fun onClick() {
        super.onClick()
        materialSwitch?.isChecked = isChecked
    }
}
```

The key points here are `init` here we assign `preference_material_switch` as the widget layout. Then we link the state of the switch with this code `materialSwitch?.isChecked = isChecked`

Then I modified the `preferences.xml` file:

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <co.kr.rtt.kogas.station_manager.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="notification_preference"
        android:title="@string/notification_preference_title"
        android:summaryOff="@string/notification_preference_summary_off"
        android:summaryOn="@string/notification_preference_summary_on" />
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <Preference
            android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"
            android:key="version_preference"
            android:summary="@string/app_version"
            android:title="@string/version_preference_title" />
        <Preference
            android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"
            android:key="privacy_policy"
            android:summary="@string/privacy_preference_summary"
            android:title="@string/privacy_preference_title" />
        <Preference
            android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:key="terms_of_service"
            android:summary="@string/tos_preference_summary"
            android:title="@string/tos_preference_title" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here I setup a new layout: `android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"` for all the preferences. I found the source code of the [`Preferences` layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="64dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/icon"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceTitleMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/accent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/icon"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLabelMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/dark" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I was able to change the color, font family, size, padding, etc. I got total control of the layout.

As you can se the `LinearLayout` instance with id `widget_frame` will be replaced with the `MaterialSwitch` instance.

I hope this will help you to have more control of your legacy apps.

Answer (score -1):

Android 2022 - most simple and straightforward method:

change in

```
/res/values/themes.xml
```

FROM

```
<!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
```

TO

```
<!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/purple_500</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution for Android Studio 3.6:

```
yourSwitch.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));
```

Changes the text color of a in the color XML file defined value (yourColor).