# How to change the color of a SwitchCompat from AppCompat library

Tags: android, switchcompat

I have a few switch controls with different colors in my application and to change their colors I used multiple custom drawable selectors.

A new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat control was introduced with the release of the AppCompat v21 library.

Is it possible to change the color of a SwitchCompat programmatically without customer drawable selector, but with XML or code?

Comment: Don't waste time looking for answers below. The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62209917/8874958

Answer (score 358, accepted):

### **AppCompat tinting attributs:**

First, you should take a look to appCompat lib article [there](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and to different attributs you can set:

**colorPrimary**: The primary branding color for the app. By default, this is the color applied to the action bar background.

**colorPrimaryDark**: Dark variant of the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to the status bar (via statusBarColor) and navigation bar (via navigationBarColor).

**colorAccent**: Bright complement to the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to framework controls (via colorControlActivated).

**colorControlNormal**: The color applied to framework controls in their normal state.

***colorControlActivated***: The color applied to framework controls in their activated (ex. checked, switch on) state.

**colorControlHighlight**: The color applied to framework control highlights (ex. ripples, list selectors).

**colorButtonNormal**: The color applied to framework buttons in their normal state.

***colorSwitchThumbNormal***: The color applied to framework switch thumbs in their normal state. (switch off)

---

### **If all custom switches are the same in a single activity:**

With previous attributes you can define your own theme for each activity:

```
<style name="Theme.MyActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

and :

```
<manifest>
...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyActivityTheme">
    </activity>
...
</manifest>
```

---

### **If you want to have differents custom switches in a single activity:**

As widget tinting in appcompat works by intercepting any layout inflation and inserting a special tint-aware version of the widget in its place (See Chris Banes [post about it](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)) you can not apply a custom style to each switch of your layout xml file. You have to set a custom Context that will tint switch with right colors.

--

<s>To do so for **pre-5.0** you need to create a Context that overlays global theme with  customs attributs and then create your switches programmatically:</s>

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Color1SwitchStyle); 
SwitchCompat sc = new SwitchCompat(ctw)
```

As of AppCompat `v22.1` you can use the following `XML` to apply a theme to the switch widget:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/Color1SwitchStyle"/>
```

Your custom switch theme:

```
<style name="Color1SwitchStyle">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</style>
```

--

On **Android 5.0** it looks like a new view attribut comes to life : `android:theme` (same as one use for activity declaration in manifest). Based on another Chris Banes [post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/), with the latter you should be able to define a custom theme directly on a view from your layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Color1SwitchStyle"/>
```

---

### **To change the track color of a SwitchCompat**

Thanks to vine'th I complete my answer with a link to SO answer that explains how to specify the Foreground of the Track when Switch is Off, it's [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879897).

Comment: Looks like "colorControlActivated" is the attribute that I need, but how to apply it for each switch? I tried to create custom theme that extends my material design theme and override this attribute. Then I setted this theme as style for Switch but it didn't work.

Comment: @Orest did you try with definnning theme in manifest file (<activity android:theme="@style/YourTheme">)

Comment: I tried your example it's not working. But if I'm using ContextThemeWrapper ctw = ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Color1SwitchStyle); SwitchCompat sc = new SwitchCompat(ctw); it's working.

Comment: ok, looks strange, I will try to find out later today

Comment: Any news on how to apply the custom style?

Comment: I update my answer after reading some post of Chris Bane about AppCompat and Style vs Theme. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Is there any way to inflate a switchcompat from xml then apply a style?

Comment: @YuriHeupa Yes it is now possible! I have edited the answer and provided a solution for **Pre 5.0** devices. Please check it out!

Comment: I have multiple switches in the same activity, how do i set different colors for each of them? The proposed solution for pre 5.0 devices, doesn't work

Comment: How about thumb and track color when activated have different color? using colorControlActivated will have both in same color. I want to different color.

Comment: After reading this, I changed the color in five minutes. I spent hours trying to figure this out last night.  Thank you!  This is the first comprehensive explanation I have found.

Comment: anyonw knows how to modify the enabled = false tint?

Comment: android:colorForeground also changes the color of the switch when it's off. That's one that I found missing from this otherwise great answer

Comment: android:colorForeground only this attribute work for me. anothers not take effects. android:colorForeground changed my switch on color, and how to change off color?

Comment: I used it but it makes the control white. Nothing inside the style has any effect.

Answer (score 83):

Ok, so I'm sorry but most of these answers are incomplete or have some minor bug in them.  The very complete answer from @austyn-mahoney is correct and the source for this answer, but it's complicated and you probably just want to style a switch.  'Styling' controls across different versions of Android is an **epic** pain in the ass.  After pulling my hair out for days on a project with very tight design constraints I finally broke down and wrote a test app and then really dug in and tested the various solutions out there for styling switches and check-boxes, since when a design has one it frequently has the other.  Here's what I found...

**First:** You can't actually style either of them, but you can apply a theme to all of them, or just one of them.

**Second:** You can do it all from XML and you don't need a second values-v21/styles.xml.

**Third:** when it comes to switches you have two basic choices if you want to support older versions of Android (like I'm sure you do)...

1. You can use a `SwitchCompat` and you will be able to make it look the same across platforms.
2. You can use a `Switch` and you will be able to theme it with the rest of your theme, or just that particular switch and on older versions of Android you'll just see an unstyled older square switch.

Ok now for the simple reference code.  Again if you create a simple Hello World! and drop this code in you can play to your hearts content.  All of that is boiler plate here so I'm just going to include the XML for the activity and the style...

activity_main.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' SwitchCompat" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        app:switchTextAppearance="@style/BrandedSwitch.text"
        app:theme="@style/BrandedSwitch.control"
        app:showText="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed SwitchCompat" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed Switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' Switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:theme="@style/BrandedSwitch"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:theme="@style/BrandedCheckBox"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml...

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch.control" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#e6e600</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#cc0000</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch.text" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffa000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedCheckBox" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#aaf000</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#39ac39</item>
</style>
```

I know, I know, you are too lazy to build this, you just want to get your code written and check it in so you can close this pain in the ass Android compatibility nightmare bug so that the designer on your team will finally be happy.  I get it.  Here's what it looks like when you run it...

API_21:

[image: API 21]

API_18:

[image: API18]

Comment: How can we set style programmatically from java file to switchcompat?

Comment: This is one of the most underrated answers on SO... btw nice beemer, I track a GSXR (mostly ride w/ Keigwins)

Comment: Thanks.  I've been to many Keigwins days, but my season pass is now with Z2.  Anyway thanks for the props, when our firm (Kunai Consulting) finds something like this to be hard to sort out we like to share our learnings.

Comment: is there a way to remove transparency?

Comment: Migrating to androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat - theme is not working

Comment: This doesn't work with `androidx`

Comment: styles have no effect. setting the theme makes the switch white but can't be customized

Answer (score 20):

I think the answer in the link below is better

[How to change the track color of a SwitchCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845595/how-to-change-the-track-color-of-a-switchcompat)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
   <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/theme</item>
   <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
   <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/grey300</item>
   <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
   <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/grey600</item>
   ...
</style>
```

Comment: unfortunatly colorSwitchThumbNormal is private ...

Answer (score 13):

So some days I lack brain cells and:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CustomSwitchStyle"/>
```

does not apply the theme because style is incorrect.  I was supposed to use app:theme :P

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/CustomSwitchStyle"/>
```

Whoopsies.  This post was what gave me insight into my mistake...hopefully if someone stumbles across this it will help them like it did me.  Thank you Gaëtan Maisse for your answer

Comment: its not working anymore.

Comment: @isuPatches, Hi, Did you understand why *style* doesn't affect *Switch* whereas *theme* does?

Comment: In my case it has worked with `android:theme` for a few years but then broke on Android 10, now `app:theme` should be used.

Answer (score 6):

To have greater control of the track color (no `API` controlled alpha changes), I extended `SwitchCompat` and style the elements programmatically:

```
    public class CustomizedSwitch extends SwitchCompat {

    public CustomizedSwitch(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public CustomizedSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public CustomizedSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public void initialize(Context context) {
        // DisplayMeasurementConverter is just a utility to convert from dp to px and vice versa
        DisplayMeasurementConverter displayMeasurementConverter = new DisplayMeasurementConverter(context);
        // Sets the width of the switch
        this.setSwitchMinWidth(displayMeasurementConverter.dpToPx((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tp_toggle_width)));
        // Setting up my colors
        int mediumGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.medium_green);
        int mediumGrey = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.medium_grey);
        int alphaMediumGreen = Color.argb(127, Color.red(mediumGreen), Color.green(mediumGreen), Color.blue(mediumGreen));
        int alphaMediumGrey = Color.argb(127, Color.red(mediumGrey), Color.green(mediumGrey), Color.blue(mediumGrey));
        // Sets the tints for the thumb in different states
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(this.getThumbDrawable(), new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[]{
                        mediumGreen,
                        ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.light_grey)
                }));
        // Sets the tints for the track in different states
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(this.getTrackDrawable(), new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[]{
                        alphaMediumGreen,
                        alphaMediumGrey
                }));
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to use the `CustomizedSwitch`, I just add one to my `xml` file.

Comment: This worked for me although I didn't find the dp to px useful here because the control width is set in xml, at least in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Be carreful of the know bug with SwitchCompat

It's a bug with corrupt file in drawable-hdpi on AppCompat
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

To fix it, juste override it with this 2 files
https://github.com/lopespm/quick-fix-switchcompat-resources
Add it on your directory drawable-hdpi

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/dev_switch_show_dev_only"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

And nothing was necessary on Java

Answer (score 2):

My working example of using style and android:theme simultaneously (API >= 21)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/wan_enable_nat_switch"
    style="@style/Switch"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/wan_enable_nat_label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<style name="Switch">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MySwitchCompat</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MySwitchCompat" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/text_outline_not_active</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, Did you understand why style doesn't work while theme does work?

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adamSwitch"
    android:textColor="@color/top_color"
    android:textAppearance="@color/top_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:showText="true"
    app:theme="@style/Custom.Widget.SwitchCompat"
    app:switchPadding="5dp"
    />
```

in style.xml

```
<style name="Custom.Widget.SwitchCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch" >
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue</item>  <!--textColor on activated state -->
      </style>
```

Answer (score -4):

Just

```
 android:buttonTint="@color/primary"
```

Comment: nah man, not working!