# How to have a Lollipop switch button

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-switch

I want to have the Lollipop style switch button for my app:

[image]

How could I implement this button so it looks like this also on older versions of android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first set `android:targetSdkVersion="22"` in your manifest to make your app compatible to **Lollipop**.

NOTE: **Color of your switch depends on this**

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

Create your own theme for your app in 
**styles.xml** in Folder **values-v21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_secondary</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml** in default Folder **values** or **values-v14**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Don't set `maxSdkVersion`. That will limit your installs up to lolipop. What you need is `targetSdkVersion`

Comment: @MirceaNistor You are right. I updated my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 46):

To have the Lollipop style switch button on older versions of android you should use SwitchCompat in layout xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/compatSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and also in java file

```
SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.compatSwitch);
```

Comment: In addition you can remove the ugly grey background that appear when you select the switch by using this piece of code : android:background="@null"

Answer (score 10):

There is a great article on the Android Developers Blog that discusses how to use material design on pre-Lollipop devices: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

To more specifically answer your question, you can use the Lollipop style switch for older versions by using the `SwitchCompat` API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html

Comment: Great answer! For styling the SwitchCompat look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26715076/457059

Answer (score 5):

API 24 on off switch

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is in that library

what this library does is to allow you to create material design switch button like in andorid 5.0

https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton

Comment: Please add a bit more information's about the libary, rather than just posting a link.

Comment: Thanks for posting this link.  I didn't know about this library.  And clicking the link provided more information!  Go figure.

Comment: @MartyMiller on The right bottom corner there is a download button from there you can download that library

Answer (score 0):

We are using SwitchCompact in lollipop version or either you can use Updated lolliopop version its better

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/compatSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />
```

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/compatSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve old type switch

[switch_old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xujTt.png)

1. update your minsdkversion and targetsdkversion to 19 and 28 respectively.

   2. update gradle dependency to 
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   3. set base app theme in style.xml like

`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>`
```

and it resolve switch with latest material design.