# I wanna create selector for Switch on both Android 5.0 and less android 5.0 application

Tags: android, themes, material-design

I wanna create theme for both Android 5.0 and less android 5.0 application.
In first case for example I have Switch that if I don't set any background it appearance will change on Android 5.0 to like a slide button as you know,

### [image]

but in less android 5.0 it show as on/off button.

### [image]

when I put

```
android:thumb="@drawable/switch_selector"
```

to change thumb image and color it's fine on android 4.4 but my Switch show nothing on Android 5.0. my question is how to create a selector or theme for Switch that can show on all devices?

**UPDATED**

in simple way, we hava many drawable folders for each screen dpi's. I wanna know if I can set drawable for each Api's as like as  for each dpi's ?!

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536198/5202007  or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908508/program-different-layouts-for-different-versions-in-android

Comment: @Tauqir my problem is not with layouts. I dont wanna create many layouts, just is there any better way to define my selector and backgrounds?

Comment: I edited my post. Get API version and use `switch` loop to change an image, I think some of additional libraries allows you to change icon look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after my hard times with Android notifications, where I need to do one method for android devices with Android 5.x and higher and another method for pre-Lollipop devices, I would advice you to search for additional libraries like this

> ### SwitchButton
>
> This project provides you a convenient way to use and customise a SwitchButton widget in Android. With just resources changed and attrs set, you can create a lifelike SwitchButton of Android 5.0+, iOS, MIUI, or Flyme and so on.
>
> Now we get the biggest movement since SwitchButton published. v1.3.0 comes with totally reconsitution and more convenient API. A wholly new demo can give you a tour in it.
>   [image]
>
> **Github page**: https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton
>   More like this you would find here: http://android-arsenal.com/

Additional libraries may help you to avoid problems with backward compatibilities of Android components.

Like you said, you add this line of code:

```
   android:thumb="@drawable/switch_selector"
```

and it works on Kitkat, but not on Lollipop.

I've found already that on Lollipop you may have much more to work. 
Just take a look here: [How to have a Lollipop switch button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752235/how-to-have-a-lollipop-switch-button)

So try to find your desired additional library like this above and let me know how it works ;-)

**EDIT:** To get API version use this:

> ```
> Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
> ```
>
> That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or
>   2.2. The problem with using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is if you have a rooted phone or custom rom, you could have a none standard OS (aka my
>   android is running 2.3.5) and that will return a null when using
>   Build.VERSION.SDK_INT so Build.VERSION.RELEASE will work no matter
>   what!
>
> To use it, you could just do this;
>
> ```
> String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
> ```
>
> From: [Retrieving Android API version programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Comment: may using existing additional libraries work fine but what if there is no library for specific thing? I updated the question plz check.

Comment: OK, finally i could not find any better solution to define a custom themes for android 5.0 and below it so I accept you answer. thanks