# Different colorControlActivated styles in Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles, android-appcompat

This is my app theme:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   ...
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_orange</item>
   ...
</style>
...
<style name="Switch" parent="Material.Widget.Switch">
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_green</item>
</style>
```

And if I use the **Switch** style:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.Switch
     style="@style/Switch"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:checked="false"/>
```

The `colorControlActivated` used it's the one inside the **BaseTheme** (orange) instead of the **Switch** one (green).
Why is this happening? Can't I have different `colorControlActivated` for different Views?
Thanks.

Comment: Read Chris Banes's article on [Theme vs Style](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/) to understand why this doesn't work and how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Good article, I've followed Chris example and replaced "style" with "android:theme" but still doesn't work :/

Comment: Hi @GuilhE, did you ever got to solve this? I'm in the exact same place right now

Comment: Hi @Nemesis no, ended up using this: https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Switch

Comment: well, got it working, i posted an answer here in case it helps anyone :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main issue is that the attribute **colorControlActivated** in the theme of the activity has preference to that attribute in any custom style that you define and apply to specific views.

The solution is (and this solution overrides the attribute for all elements in the same activity in the same way) to create a new theme and apply that theme to your activity in the manifest. This theme could inherit from your main theme and override only the attributes you need.

The themes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- items-->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- items-->
</style>

<style name="lightAppTheme" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

The manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".application.appname"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/lightAppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
 </application>
```

I hope this helps anyone that comes into this since it took me some hours to get it working.

In order to make different elements in the same activity to use different **colorControlActivated** atributes, go to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat).