# SwitchCompat change color

Tags: android, android-support-library

I need to change SwitchCompat's track color.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat), but it didn't worked for me.
This is code of my XML file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/sc_push"
    style="@style/switchStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:theme="@style/switchStyle"
    app:theme="@style/switchStyle" />
```

and this is my style.xml file

```
<style name="switchStyle">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/gray</item>
</style>
```

What seems the problem?

In addition, I can't change the activity's color or base application's color. I have to change color for this single view.

Comment: why you use   android:theme="@style/switchStyle"
    app:theme="@style/switchStyle" , use ONLY ONE at a time

Comment: @bpA android:theme is for Lollipop+, and app:theme was for KitKat and lower version but only android:theme worked.

Comment: yes . for that use different version files like v-21 etc

Answer (score 15):

Try this code.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       ...
       <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
       <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/theme</item>
       <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
       <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/grey300</item>
       <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
       <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/grey600</item>
       ...
    </style>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: added above code your values-style folder and also added your manifest file.

Comment: how to change only thumb color ?

Comment: if I want to set the thumb color to green for example and the the track color to be white, is it possible ??

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do it would be,

1. Create new resource file as below, switch_track_color.xml, using selector tag.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="#15A215" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="#BAC7CB" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

2. Use this in style for SwitchCompat.

```
<style name="SwitchStyle">
   <item name="thumbTint">#ffffff</item>
   <item name="trackTint">@color/switch_track_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: With pleasure ! Thanks you for the good answer !

Comment: This is perfect answer

Comment: Thank you so much! was stuck on the same problem, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922772/13755907), which I like, because it is the only one I found working 100% with androidx SwitchCompat, I would enhance it slightly. Above just changes track color. It is quite obvious that to have both elements' colors changed (track and thumb) you need to have it like this (here is orchid color as base):

1. Add in color resource directory 2 files

switch_thumb_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#BA55D3" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:color="#A9A9A9" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

switch_track_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#6FBA55D3" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:color="#4CFFFFFF" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

2. Add in themes.xml the style for the SwitchCompat

   ```
    <style name="SwitchStyle">
    <item name="thumbTint">@color/switch_thumb_color</item>
    <item name="trackTint">@color/switch_track_color</item>
   ```