# Providing track drawable to switch messes up appearance

Tags: java, android, xml, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to set a custom drawable as track to a switch, but when I do that, it makes the thumb fill the track instead of overflowing it.

Switch without custom drawable:

[image]

Switch with the custom drawable applied:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Style of the switch:

```
<style name="switch_style">
    <item name="android:track">@drawable/switch_track_selector</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb_selector</item>
</style>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `SwitchComapt` instead of switch and changing the theme.
You can have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat).

**Edit**

if you are using the support libraries then you don't need any specific them even,
Your `SwichComapt` will be automatically as per your current theme.

Comment: bounty points well spent (altough I need to wait a few hours for that), thanks a lot for your help, it finally works! :)