# Define a custom style (theme) on an Android Switch component

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme, nine-patch

I'm new to Android development and also on Android theming/customization that looks to be a wide subject...

I'm trying to give my Switch component a special look & feel, but I don't manage to achieve what I want, avan after looking many resources on internet.

**This is driving me crazy!!**
Thanks in advance for your help, Android masters !

## The context

I work on an existing android application (v1) that was minSdkVersion="8".

Because of this, the application used 3rd-party libraries to get actionbar ([ActionBar Sherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)) and switches ([SwitchCompatLibrary](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary)) :

Today, we are making the v2 version, with minSdkVersion="14".

Our customer also ask us to change the default switch look and feel.

The target is to have thiese switches :
[image]
[image]

This really looks like the latest material design switches, but with the orange color instead of the "green-blue" color, like [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch).

## The constraints

As we are now minSdk 14, we could remove the 2 libraries "ActionBarSherlock" and "SwitchCompatLibrary", but **this is NOT an option.** Indeed, we do not have time for that...

Indeed, I tried to add in dependencies in my project's gradle file the **appcompat-v7**, in order to try using the native switch component with material theme inside ([see here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)) but this gives me errors because of duplicate attributes definitions with the 2 libs mentionned above. So I can't use it, and I'm not sure this should have work...

```
dependencies {
(...)

compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
compile project(':switchCompatLibrary')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

// incompatible avec actionbarsherlock and SwitchCompatLibrary...
// compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+" 

(...)
}
```

## Existing code

So here is the actuel code.

In my layout.xml file, I use the SwitchCompatLibrary switch :

```
        <de.ankri.views.Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchButtonNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

In my themes.xml file :

```
<style name="Theme.Orange" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    ...
    <!-- Theme switch with SwitchCompatLibrary -->
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_light</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

with styling informations defined in the SwitchCompatLibrary itself like this

styles.xml :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="switch_light">
        <item name="track">@drawable/switch_track_holo_light</item>
        <item name="thumb">@drawable/switch_inner_holo_light</item>
        <item name="textOn">@string/textOn</item>
        <item name="textOff">@string/textOff</item>
        <item name="thumbTextPadding">12dip</item>
        <item name="switchMinWidth">96dip</item>
        <item name="switchPadding">16dip</item>
        <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    </style>    

    <style name="TextAppearance">
        <item name="textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="textColorHighlight">?android:attr/textColorHighlight</item>
        <item name="textColorHint">?android:attr/textColorHint</item>
        <item name="textColorLink">?android:attr/textColorLink</item>
        <item name="textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

switch_inner_holo_light.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

switch_track_holo_light.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused_holo_light" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

And the result is this:
[image]
[image]

## What I tried

#### Use the native switch

As I'm now API 14 minimum, I first tried to replace the "de.ankri.views.Switch" with "android.widget.Switch" in my layout.xml, but the styling was not applying anymore (blue activated switch instead or orange)...
[image]
[image]

However, defining directly in each switch the theme ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch)) seems to work better as I have an orange switch back :

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchButtonNotification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:checked="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_inner_holo_light"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track_holo_light"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Strange... I don't know why, so I will not do that and keep "de.ankri.views.Switch" component.

#### Use the SwitchCompatLibrary switch and do my own styling

Then I tried to keep "de.ankri.views.Switch" component and do the same thing than SwitchCompatLibrary, but overriding the "@style/switch_light" style with my own one, using new drawables for track and thumb

themes.xml :

```
<style name="Theme.Orange" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    ...
    <!-- Theme switch with SwitchCompatLibrary -->
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/Switch.Orange</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml :

```
<style name="Switch.Orange" parent="@style/switch_light">
    <item name="track">@drawable/switch_track_orange</item>
    <item name="thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb_orange</item>
    <item name="textOn">@string/textOn</item>
    <item name="textOff">@string/textOff</item>
    <item name="thumbTextPadding">12dip</item>
    <item name="switchMinWidth">96dip</item>
    <item name="switchPadding">16dip</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

switch_thumb_orange.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_normal_orange" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_orange" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_orange" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_normal_orange" />
</selector>
```

switch_thumb_activated_orange.9.png
[image]

switch_thumb_normal_orange.9.png
[image]

switch_track_orange.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_normal_orange" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_activated_orange" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_activated_orange" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_normal_orange" />
</selector>
```

switch_track_activated_orange.9.png
[image]

switch_track_normal_orange.9.png
[image]

#### Results :

And the result is just AWFUL !! :
[image]
[image]

Where am I wrong ? 
I tried to change the "thumbTextPadding", "switchMinWidth" and "switchPadding" in styles.xml, but without good results.

Perhaps my 9-patch files are wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This post describes what you need: http://www.materialdoc.com/switch/

If the coloring doesn't work (api < 21), take a look at
[this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch)

 Hope this helps you !

Answer (score -1):

As a first step, I suggest you to replace actionBarSherlock with support.v7.app.ActionBar. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)

This migration needs some time because you must redefine your existing styling. In my memory, when I have made a similar migration, the code of v7 styling looks like actionBarSherlock styling. At this time, v7 ActionBar was named ActionBarCompat.

Answer (score -2):

**You can try this:**

- Make an image for the background of your switch.
- That must have a height equal to that of your circle.
- And the top and the bottom of the image must look like this:

[image: http://screenshot.sh/owpTUNk8jTtUl]