# How to change the inside color of Switch button pragmatically in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the inside color of a switch button to green when it is checked but its only change the background color . Here is my code. Please help me . I want to change the color only through programatically

```
switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

switchButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the track drawable using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setTrackDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable). You should be able to just use a `ColorDrawable` instance:

```
switchButton.setTrackDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

EDIT: try using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setThumbDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setThumbResource(int)? One thing to note is that if you replace the thumb drawable with a ColorDrawable it may not actually look the same: not sure you can only change the color with a simple drawable, you may need to create a more complex XML Drawable to do that.

Comment: It's only change the button background

Comment: Did you mean switchButton.setThumbTintList(Color.GREEN); It shows an error

Comment: No, thumb resource or drawable: tint list is different.

Comment: I don't want to add custom switch. I just want to edit the color of default switch button. Default switch button shows red color when it is checked, I want to make it as green

Comment: Ah. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch: maybe that helps.