# Retain color of Switch when disabeld

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a Switch in xamarin forms. When I toggle, the color is Pink when true and grey when false.

When I disable the switch as I do not want the user to toggle. then the color change to Grey.

How can i retain the color of the Switch. When it is disable and it is true it should be in default color but not grey,

Could you please suggest how can i achieve this.

```
<Switch IsToggled="True" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Thanks
Rao

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated a bit this problem and I can see two solutions:

### Easy way

Use a private boolean variable instead of using the `IsEnabled` property. Then when the clicked event is handled, check the switch's status with the variable.

### Hard way

Overwrite the Switch control to get this behaviour. You can follow [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/).

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the [`Switch`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/) for `Xamarin.Forms`, there is currently no option of specifying the color. Conclusively, you will have to create your own renderer for both `iOS` and `Android`.

## Android

Essentially, what you need to do is to override the `OnElementChanged` and `OnCheckChanged` events and check for the `Checked` Property of the `Control`. Afterwards, you can set the `ThumbDrawable` of the `Control` and execute `SetColorFilter` with the color you want to apply. Doing so although requires Android 5.1+. An example is given [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/249767/#Comment_249767).

You could also create utilise the [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) and add new [`ColorDrawables`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable/) for the [`StateChecked`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.StateChecked/), [`StateEnabled`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.StateEnabled/) and lastly, a default value as well. This is supported for Android 4.1+. An example of using the `StateListDrawable` is provided in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25635526/2399772).

## iOS

iOS is somewhat more simple. Simply create your own `SwitchRenderer`, override the `OnElementChanged` event and set the [`OnTintColor`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UISwitch+UISwitchAppearance.OnTintColor/) and [`ThumbTintColor`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.UIKit.UISwitch.ThumbTintColor/).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make custom renderer for your control in this case switch like that and set color when it changes:

```
class CustomSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(this.Control.Checked ? Color.DarkGreen : Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(this.Control.Checked ? Color.Green : Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);

        this.Control.CheckedChange += this.OnCheckedChange;
    }

    private void OnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Control.ThumbDrawable.SetColorFilter(this.Control.Checked ? Color.DarkGreen : Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        this.Control.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(this.Control.Checked ? Color.Green : Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
    }
}
```