# How to change switch button color in android

Tags: android, button, layout, colors, switch-statement

I have this Switchbutton

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text"
    android:textColor="@color/foreground" />
```

How can I change the color of the button when the button is checked from default to my color?

Update:

I've tried this solution: [Change "on" color of a Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch)

but when I change from Switch to SwitchCompat, I can't see any Switch Buttons more

FYI I use `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback">`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change "on" color of a Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the color of the switch button programaticly

```
int myColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor);
int defaultColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultColor);

public void changeSwitch(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
    if (checked) {
        ((Switch) view).getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(myColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        ((Switch) view).getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(myColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    } else {
        ((Switch) view).getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(defaultColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        ((Switch) view).getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(defaultColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```