# Change Switch color in Navigation Drawer menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch

I'm having trouble changing the color of my Navigation drawer switch items. I want each one to have a custom color associated with it's action.

I've defined my nav drawer with a menu like this:

```
<item
    android:title="@string/nav_drawer_services_title">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Red_selector"
                android:title="@string/nav_drawer_red_title"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Blue_selector"
                android:title="@string/nav_drawer_blue_title"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

My switch_layout.xml is like this:

```
<Switch
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="toggleService"
android:checkable="true"
android:checked="true"
style="@style/MyCustomSwitchTheme"
/>
```

I've tried changing `MyCustomSwitchTheme` as suggessted here: [Change "on" color of a Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253512/change-on-color-of-a-switch), yet the switch items remain the same color.

Why doesn't my custom theme style override the default? I can't seem to change these switches from the `colorAccent` defined in my `colors.xml` and `AppTheme`.

Anyone know a way around this?

**Edit:** Here is the styles code, sorry about not including that with the OP.

```
<style name="MyCustomSwitchTheme">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#46bdbf</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/light_gray_color</item>

    <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't see any color changing statement. Please post your theme code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `android:theme="@style/MyCustomSwitchTheme"`

instead `style="@style/MyCustomSwitchTheme"`

Comment: Wow... I'm dumb. (Or at least have been staring at the screen too long today.) I hate it when I overlook the little typos before posting a question. Thanks though, you are correct!