# How to make material floating action button with inner rings?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I would like to make a floating action button that has an outer ring and inner ring. I need those both to be clickable. Right now I have an ImageView with the src set to a drawable I created. The layout looks simple and I want to give it a better look and feel.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/target_1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/target_zone"
    app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/blue_target"
    app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="210"
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="275dp" />
```

```
//target_zone.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding
                android:bottom="50dp"
                android:left="50dp"
                android:right="50dp"
                android:top="50dp" />
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="70dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: you want rings be clickable?

Comment: @EliasFazel Yes the inside and outer ring clickable

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845139/android-make-list-item-with-background-clickable

Comment: And do you mean to click and perform function or just change the state of color in drawable?

Comment: I would like to perform a function. Id like to reference it and apply onClickListener

Comment: The more important part is applying this drawable to the background of a fab with it using the full size of the fab.

Comment: you have to use 2 imageView and define click listener. you cannot perform click funtion on a drawable.