# Requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Tags: android, xml, colors, attributes, drawable

I have seen the previous answers to this kind of question but none of them worked for me so i'll go ahead and post it again. My log cat says:

> " Binary XML file line #7:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable"

in line #7 my xml is: `<item ... <solid android:drawable="@color/hex"/> ... </item>`

and:  `<item android:selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end after a lot of trying and searching the answer that fited me was here: [Selector on background color of TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview)

Answer (score 1):

use argb colors instead like:

```
<solid android:drawable="#006633"/>
```

Comment: How about @Sumighosh Charuvil 's answer.

Comment: <solid android:drawable="#006633"/> I believe this will do

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
<solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
```