# TextView Selectable and drawable background

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button, android-styles

I've TextView. I need to make it clickable, white and with "selectable effect", besides I need it to have a rectangular white border, to fake a button borders:

[image: TextView example]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@drawable/white_empty_rectangle"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

I can't set two background properties...how can I somehow "intersect" the two properties?

EDIT: I only need the borders of the rectangle, so it is "empty", I should see the background color behind the TextView.

Comment: do you have any picture of what are you trying to achieve? It will improve your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295522/4848308 you should use background selector.
This one to achieve border line background https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496310/4848308

I hope it helps!

Comment: You perfectly right but I've to guess the system color of the pressed state of the background, I'd like to remain with ?android:selectableItemBackground if possible. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: You have to use the selector as suggestet. Another option would be to use an ImageButton if you don't need input to your TextView (but which you need I guess).

Comment: What do you mean by "input to your TextView"?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_empty_white"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```