# change background Image textView when pressed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

i use this method but it is not worked. 
in drawable i created selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/reponseclicked">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/repons">
    </item>
</selector>
```

and this my TextView

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:text="text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of "not worked"? Till then the question is not fit for SO as it doesn't have an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Chnage `android:state_pressed="false"` to  `android:state_pressed="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/reponseclicked" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/repons"/>
</selector>
```

[**See this Thread.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview)

Answer (score 0):

`<color name="colorControlHighlight">#B6B6B6</color>`

This in your Drawable

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorControlHighlight"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorControlHighlight"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Also
This in your Drawable v21 will give you ripple effect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</ripple>
```

Your Textview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:text="text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView is not clickable by default. So first enable them as below.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```