# SetBackgroundResource on listview custom adapter getting error

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create a custom listview row color inside my adapter

Here is my xml

### artists_list_backgroundcolor

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:color="#6495ED" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
   android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
     android:color="#E5F5FA" />
</selector>
```

and here is my code inside adapter

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CategoryPreview, null, false);

        }

        TextView txtCategoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryName);
        txtCategoryName.Text = mitems[position].CategoryName;
        TextView txtCategoryID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCategoryID);
        txtCategoryID.Text = mitems[position].CategoryID;

        row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);

        return row;
    }
```

When activity is going to start i'm getting error

Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Drawable WiOrderAndroid.WiOrderAndroid:drawable/artists_list_backgroundcolor with resource ID #0x7f020053

It work only if i will set my xml with this way.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#ef4444" />

    </shape>
  </item>

</selector>
```

But is this the right way?

Comment: No i got the same error again

Comment: Hello, could you tell me what do you want? Because you have misunderstand the `SetBackgroundResource` method and `ColorStateList`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use R.drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor instead

Comment: It is the same in xamarin, i think something is going on with my xml\

Comment: No problem i found a solution i will post it now. if i will set the shape inside my xml it works. But it is this method the right way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:color="#6495ED" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
   android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
     android:color="#E5F5FA" />
</selector>
```

From above codes, what you have defined is a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource), it should be in the `res/color/artists_list_backgroundcolor.xml` path, not `res/drawable/` , and it should be referred by `@color/artists_list_backgroundcolor` or `Resource.Color.artists_list_backgroundcolor`.

What you need is a `drawable selector`. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview)

### Update:

[`SetBackgroundResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)) method:

> Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

The resource should be in `drawable` folder, but your `artists_list_backgroundcolor` file belongs to [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource), it should be in the `/res/color/` folder, not `drawable` folder.

If you want to use your `artists_list_backgroundcolor` file ,you need put it in the `/res/color/` folder. But you can't use it by `row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);`, please refer to [this](https://adilatwork.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-how-to-use-colorstatelist.html) to use the `ColorStateList`.